# How to install the Data Sense app?

Tags: apps, data-usage

I was checking out some Windows Phone FAQs and came across [one about an app called Data Sense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage), that helps users track their data usage.

The FAQ seems to suggest that the app should be pre-installed on phones, but it's not on mine, and I can't find it in the store.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it depends on the carrier.

If your carrier "supports" Data Sense the app will be available in settings, near background tasks.

If you carrier does not support is not currently possible to make it available.

Looks like unbranded phones does not have this support too.

I'm getting in touch with Nokia to clarify with my unbranded Lumia did not come with DataSense.

They will said that the carrier need to support Data Sense but I didn't buy that since my HTC 8x has Data Sense and works with the same carrier I'm using right now.

Comment: Looks like it may be more common with an update coming in the Summer (see bottom): http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/05/14/nokia-s-first-metal-windows-phone-arrives-meet-the-sexy-lumia-925.aspx

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Very good.

Answer (score 1):

The application comes with the [GDR2 update](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history) of Windows Phone 8.

It does not depend of the carrier, as long as they don't uninstall the application before delivering the handset to you because ATM there is no way to download the app from the store.

I have an unbranded trial Lumia 925 and it does have the app running perfectly with my Vodafone Spain SIM card. [The configuration is 100% manual](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage), nothing is synced with the carrier.

Update: some people (including me) are reporting that even if the app is merely informative and manually configured some carriers have opted to no deliver it with the update and it seems [Microsoft has just updated the How-To to state that](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage). My case: Vodafone Spain, epic fail.